# How to set ws.title to today's date with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am pulling a list from a sharepoint site using shareplum. The output is saved locally in an excel file. There is only one sheet created. I need to set the name of the worksheet to the date user will run the script.
So, if i run the script today in order to pull the data from the sharepoint, I need the title to be today's date. The list on the sharepoint is updated dynamically, so i need to know what the excel file represents (the date where it was created).
I tried:
`ws.title = datetime.now()`
and
`ws.title = date.today()`

Unfortunately this did not do the trick

Comment: I think you need date as string in that, strftime()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: It worked by changing the / with an -. With / i got an error: " Invalid character / found in sheet title"

Comment: I think  it is because in your case you needed to write \/ instead of /